# Filter markers by date in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, leaflet-plugins

I built a photo map with Leaflet which contains geotagged photos. I managed to fetch the timestamp and coordinates of the pictures with a php script and now I want to filter the images by it's recording date. The JSON Data of the imported images contain information about year, month and day.

This is my Leaflet setup:

```
var photoLayer = L.photo.cluster({ spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1.2 }).on('click', function (evt) {
                evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template('<span class="DatumPopup">Aufnahmedatum: {DateTimeOriginal} <span class="Uhrzeit">{Time}</span><img src="{url}" height="auto" width="100%"/>', evt.layer.photo), {
                    className: 'leaflet-popup-photo',
                    minWidth: 400
                }).openPopup();
            });

            //Call the next function as soon as the page loads
            window.onload = callForImages()

            //Makes a request, loading the getimages.php file
            function callForImages() {

                //Create the request object
                var httpReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                //When it loads,
                httpReq.onload = function() {

                    //Convert the result back into JSON
                    var result = JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText);

                    //Load the images
                    loadImages(result);
                }

                //Request the page
                try {
                    httpReq.open("GET", "getphotos.php", true);
                    httpReq.send(null);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }


            //Generates the images and sticks them into the photolayer
            function loadImages(images) {
                var photos = [];
                //Loop over the images
                for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                    photos.push({
                        lat: images[i].lat,
                        lng: images[i].lng,
                        url: images[i].filename,
                        DateTimeOriginal: images[i].DateTimeOriginal,
                        Year: images[i].Year,
                        YearMonth: images[i].YearMonth,
                        Time: images[i].Time,

                        //If you have thumbnails, switch the comments on the following lines.
                        thumbnail: images[i].filename
                        //thumbnail: images[i].thumbnail
                    });
                }
                photoLayer.add(photos).addTo(map);
                //Add the photos to the map
                map.fitBounds(photoLayer.getBounds());
                //Zoom the map to the photos
            }

}).addTo( map );
```

How can I apply a filter(filter by day f.e.) to the json data in the loadimages function? I'd like to filter by button click or do a range slider(But I think this one is quite compliacted).

Comment: Where/when you want to apply filter? I suppose not in the `loadImages` function, since this could easily be done. Some UI selection after all is loaded? Please edit your question with additional details.

Comment: I think applying it in the loadImages function would be the best idea performance wise. Still, I am not quite sure how to start here. The filter then should be bound to a graphical element like a button or a slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible way to dynamically filter displayed photos would be to first load all photos in some global array `photos` and then when needed, first clean `photoLayer` and then add desired/filtered photos based on some global min/max values `startDate` and `endDate` into `photoLayer`.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var photoLayer = L.photo.cluster({
  spiderfyDistanceMultiplier: 1.2
});
photoLayer.on('click', function (evt) {
  evt.layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template('<span class="DatumPopup">Aufnahmedatum: {DateTimeOriginal} <span class="Uhrzeit">{Time}</span><img src="{url}" height="auto" width="100%"/>', evt.layer.photo), {
    className: 'leaflet-popup-photo',
    minWidth: 400
  }).openPopup();
});

var photos = [];
var startDate = null;
var endDate = null;

function getAllImages(images) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    photos.push({
      lat: images[i].lat,
      lng: images[i].lng,
      url: images[i].filename,
      DateTimeOriginal: images[i].DateTimeOriginal,
      Year: images[i].Year,
      YearMonth: images[i].YearMonth,
      Time: images[i].Time,
      thumbnail: images[i].filename
    });
  }
}

function loadFilteredImages() {
  var filteredPhotos = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
    if (startDate && (photos[i].DateTimeOriginal < startDate))
    || (endDate && (photos[i].DateTimeOriginal > endDate)) continue;
    filteredPhotos.push(photos[i]);
  }
  photoLayer.clearLayers();
  if (filteredPhotos.length > 0) {
    photoLayer.add(filteredPhotos);
    if (!map.hasLayer(photoLayer) photoLayer.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(photoLayer.getBounds());
  }
}

function callForImages() {
  var httpReq = (window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  httpReq.onload = function() {
    var result = JSON.parse(httpReq.responseText);
    getAllImages(result);
    loadFilteredImages();
  }
  try {
    httpReq.open("GET", "getphotos.php", true);
    httpReq.send(null);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

window.onload = callForImages();
```

This way when needed you can just change `startDate` and `endDate` values and call `loadFilteredImages()` function.